# Count Occurence of a Regex Search Term

Tags: google-sheets, regex

Using `CTRL+F` indicates the number of occurrences of a search term. However,  when using regex (via Find and Replace) there's no indication of count.

Does anyone know how to find the number of occurrences when using regex?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"something","$ ."),"$"))
```

This replace the regex pattern your looking for with a symbol, then counts the number of times it occurs in your string, but counting the number of cells it splits into.

note: the extra space and the period at the end of the regexreplace, is there in case your pattern happens to be the last thing in the sentence, or cell value, that way it still has data to split into the final cell.

Answer (score 1):

### For single line string:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(D2, "[$]", ""), "pattern", "$"), "[^$]", ""))
```

### For multi line string:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(D2, "[$]", ""), "pattern", "$"), "([^$]|\n)", ""))
```

### Explanations

- `REGEXREPLACE(D2, "[$]", "")` remove existing `$` chars
- then replace the pattern with `$`
- then remove all other characters.
- now the number of `$`s left is the number of patterns.

### Notes

- Use another placeholder char if `$` is in pattern.
- Use `([^$]|\n)*` instead of `*` in multi-line pattern.